# Message in Qt doesn't get translated

Tags: c++, qt

I've created translation for my application. I've installed `QTranslator` instance with translations file loaded and it seems to be working, except for a single case and only that case.

There is one class with method, which looks like this:

```
QString MultiEditorNumeric::getTabLabel()
{
    return tr("Number");
}
```

The message was noticed by `lupdate`, I translated it and released with `lrelease`, but in runtime, the message returned from the method is still `"Number"`.

I even modified method, because I couldn't belive it:

```
QString MultiEditorNumeric::getTabLabel()
{
    QString s = tr("Number");
    qDebug() << s;
    return s;
}
```

Yes, this is the exact place, where the number doesn't get translated. Debug message doesn't lie.

I release translations under file named with `.qm` suffix. This file is added to my project resources and is compiled into the binary. I've tried removing the qm file from resources and re-adding it, but it didn't help.

What else can I do? What can I check?

Comment: Attaching qm file might be helpful.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/muw84gubozu0wdu/guiSQLiteStudio_pl.qm?dl=0

Comment: the file indeed seems to contain Number => Liczba translation. Are you sure you are loading new translation file?

Comment: As I mentioned - I did remove and re-add the file to resources, then relinked the application. All other messages are translated, so the file is loaded and since I just re-added it, it should be fresh.

Comment: Just now I've cleared and compiled the entire application from the beginning and still no luck.

Comment: MultiEditorNumeric class inherits QObject?

Comment: @Meefte: Yes, it inherits from `QWidget`. I even have few more classes similar to that one - all of them have this `getTabLabel()` method and for them it works just fine. It's really, really weird to me. I have no more ideas what could be wrong.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer - I will post anwer as soon as I can - or if anyone else wants, fell free to answer and I will accept it. So the deal is that my class didn't have `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class declaration. I didn't notice it from `lupdate`, because my script to run `lupdate` was silencing all messages from `lupdate`. I've added `Q_OBJECT` and it immediately started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My class didn't have `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class declaration. I didn't notice it from `lupdate`, because my script to run `lupdate` was silencing all messages from `lupdate`. I've added `Q_OBJECT` and it immediately started to work.